# Error during pg_restore: text search dictionary "unaccent" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.3, unaccent

I'm trying to move data between servers. I recreated the whole database structure, checked that same users exist and the `unaccent` extension that we use is enabled for all schemas of the target database.

When I try to run:

```
pg_restore -h %server_host% -a -c --disable-triggers -d %db_name% -U %user_name% 2014-12-09.custom
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "contracts":
> ERROR:  text search dictionary "unaccent" does not exist
> ```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'd say you haven't installed the contrib modules. They're often packaged separately.

Comment: @CraigRinger postgresql-contrib-9.3 package is installed  into the system and I can use unaccent, so unfortunately this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

It came out that there was a stupid hack, unaccent function was marked immutable and there was an index that used this unaccent function. Dropping the index and recreating it after backup did the trick.

Do not use hacks, folks :)

Comment: There is a better alternative to the hack that caused the trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11007216/939860